# Нужно написать функцию, которая получает целое значение и возвращает число с обратным порядком цифр. Например, для 7631 функция должна вернуть 1367

Tags: c, функции

Код не работает так, как должен
Укажите пожалуйста на мои ошибки

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int func(int ch)
{
    int result = 0;
    while (ch != 0)
    {
        result = (result * 10) + (ch % 10);
        ch = (ch - (ch % 10)) / 10;
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 7631;
    func(a);
    printf("%d", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Напишите

```
a = func(a);
```

вместо просто

```
func(a);
```

иначе вы теряете все, что сделано в функции...

Да, вот тут

```
ch = (ch - (ch % 10)) / 10;
```

достаточно просто

```
ch = ch / 10;
```

(или, что то же самое, `ch /= 10;`) - в силу целочисленности деления.